# empty list view from sqlite cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a sqlite with 5 record and i want to populate a list view with a cursor from this bbdd, but only create a list view with a white places, any places for a result of bddd query, without content. I think is for the textview color but no. Anyone can helps me?

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    setContentView(R.layout.listatab);

     //Creamos la instancia de DataBaseHelper, un cursor y aplicamos el metodo getNombres al cursor.
     ayudabbdd = new DataBaseHelper(this);
     Cursor nombresC;     
     nombresC = (Cursor) ayudabbdd.getNombres();  
     nombresC.moveToFirst();
     startManagingCursor(nombresC);
     String[] datosRecibidos = new String[] {"nombre"};
    int[] layoutDondeLoPongo = new int[] { R.layout.entrada_lista};

     //Mientras el cursor no este vacio rellenamos la lista con el adaptador, que nos sirve para conectar unos datos con el listview.
     if(nombresC!=null){
         SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listatab, nombresC,datosRecibidos, layoutDondeLoPongo); 
         this.setListAdapter(adapter);
     this.getListView();  
     }
```

Listatab.xml

```
    android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and entradalista.xml

```
android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nombre"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="28dip"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried my answer.? Just replace it with your code and try it..

Comment: Look at my newly edited answer, Remove your code and put my code and try it.. Let me know what happen..

Comment: Same, all results is empty, but is the correct number of results

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**EDIT::**

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
setContentView(R.layout.listatab);

 //Creamos la instancia de DataBaseHelper, un cursor y aplicamos el metodo getNombres al cursor.
  ayudabbdd = new DataBaseHelper(this);
  Cursor nombresC;     
  nombresC = (Cursor) ayudabbdd.getNombres();  
  nombresC.moveToFirst();
  startManagingCursor(nombresC);
  getListView(); 
 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.listatab,nombresC,        
  new String[] {"nombre"},   
  new int[] { R.id.nombre}); 
  setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Same result..can i debug to see if the cursor is populate correctly? I don't know to saw the value of the cursor result

Comment: just nombresC.getCount(); Log.e("Size of cursor:",nombresC.getCount());

Comment: Any new idea?i will be crazy with this!

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
int[] layoutDondeLoPongo = new int[] { R.layout.entrada_lista};
String[] datosRecibidos = new String[] {"nombre"};
```

to:

```
int[] layoutDondeLoPongo = new int[] { R.id.nombre };
String[] datosRecibidos = new String[] {"son"};
```

Comment: Same result if i change int[] layoutDondeLoPongo = new int[] { R.id.nombre };

Comment: Debug using `nombresC.getCount()` (should return 5), and `nombresC.getColumnNames()` (should return String[] {"nombre"}). If this is not the case, then it means your SQL query is wrong, or your result set doesnt have a `column` named `nombre`

Comment: Log.e("debugeando", "son "+nombresC.getCount());
 Log.e("debugeando", "son "+nombreC.getColumNames()                           It return 6 and  son [Ljava.lang.String;@4052ceb0

Comment: Crash, son column doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

listatab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<ListView  
     android:id="@android:id/list"
     android:cacheColorHint="#666666"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

entrada_lista.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- row.xml -->
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:paddingTop="4dip"
 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
 android:paddingBottom="6dip"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical">

 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

 <TextView android:id="@+id/nombreLugar"
    android:textColor="#4B89E0" 
     android:layout_width="130dip"
     android:layout_height="40dip"
     android:textSize = "15dip"
     />


</LinearLayout>          

</LinearLayout>
```

and the activity

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    setContentView(R.layout.listatab);

   //Creamos la instancia de DataBaseHelper, un cursor y aplicamos el metodo getNombres al cursor.
    ayudabbdd = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    Cursor nombresC;     
    nombresC = (Cursor) ayudabbdd.getNombres();  
    nombresC.moveToFirst();
    startManagingCursor(nombresC);
    String[] from = new String[]{DataBaseHelper.CNOMBRE};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.nombreLugar};
    SimpleCursorAdapter lugares = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.entrada_lista, nombresC, from, to);
    setListAdapter(lugares);

  }
```